# Чи існує термін "токарка" в українській літературній мові?

Tags: терміни

В Інтернеті трапляється це слово, особливо часто його використовують блогери. Наприклад,одним із таких є [Дядько Максим](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTT1HwQapHU).

На [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0&t=0) згадується лише сама професія "токар", але у темах: "Таблиця відмін і зразки відмінювання","Поділ іменників І і II відмін на групи" та "Іменник".

Під час перегляду [Словника української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/tokarka), мені вискакує інформація, що "слова «токарка» не знайдено."

Якщо ж цього слова в українській мові немає, тоді звідки воно взялось на наших теренах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здається, слово «токарка» не є повністю нейтральним (інакше б словники його згадували). Можливо, воно належить до розмовної або професійної лексики (а в деяких значеннях застаріле). Але воно утворено цілком за традиціями українського словотвору — суфікс *-к-* часто вживаються на позначення предметів/інструментів, пов'язаних із якоюсь дією (порівняйте: [дроба́рка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=25053&page=833), [клеєва́рка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=42071&page=1329) (у 2-му значенні), [те́рка](http://sum.in.ua/s/terka) (у значеннях 1–2)). Тому часто вживається, на позначення різних предметів, пов'язаних із дієсловом «[точи́ти](http://sum.in.ua/s/tochyty)»:

- «Етнографічний збірник», 1896, ст. 153:

  > тока́рка, тока́рник — ведро;
- Юліян Тарнович, «Лемківщина», 1941, ст. 140 (або [«Матеріальна культура Лемківщини»](http://www.lemko.org/lih/beskid/index.html), 1972, ст. 138):

  > Така деревяна токарка, прикріплена до двох дощок, обертається на рухомому дрючку й точить підложений кусок дерева малими долотами у бажану форму.
- Олекса Горбач, «Арґо українських лірників», 1957, ст. 39:

  > тока́рка, -а́рник «відро» («те, в що точать вино»?);
- Календар «Провидіння», 1962, ст. 165:

  > По прийнятті до школи учень одержує малу прецизійну токарку, якою користується аж до закінчення школи. <…> Під час навчання кожний учень виробляє власноручно чотири годинники <…>.
- «Український самостійник», 1966, частина 4 (498), Атанас Фіґоль, стаття «Кiбернетика модерне суспiльство», ст. 22:

  > В iндустрiї широко застосованi автоматичнi станки для обробки всiлякого приладдя — токарки, фризерки, вертiльницi тощо, як теж автоматичнi пристрої для втримання постiйних фiзикальних величин — температури, скорости, тиснення — т. зв. гомеостати.
- Степан Любомирський, «Слідами заповіту. Частина 1: Поховайте та вставайте!», 1985, ст. 140:

  > Він записався на металюргічний курс, щоб мати доступ до токарки і на цьому курсі треба буде йому досидіти до кінця, щоб оминути найменших підозр чуйних органів безпеки.
- Ісаак Десяк, «Від Праги до Москви», 1986, ст. 174:

  > В цій майстерні були різні машини (токарка, шепінґ, шліфярка і т. д.).
- Євген Шевченко, «Українська народна тканина», 1990, стаття «Верстат», ст. 61:

  > ВЕРСТА́Т (ВАРСТА́Т) — <…>. Різновиди В. за функцією: кросна, тканиця, <…>, токарка, <…>.
- Микола Домашевський, «Історія Гуцульщини. Том 1», 1995, стаття «Юра Шкрібляк (1822–1884)», ст. 456:

  > А коли підріс, то сам зладнав собі примітивну маленьку токарку, на якій почав точити звичайні тарілочки та куделі.
- Йосип Кульчик, «Мир дому твоєму», 1997, ст. 83:

  > Цяпка розумів, що пістоля стала для Миколки заповітною мрією, але не <…> мав сили розстатися із своїм талісманом. Миколі роздобуто тяжку «токарку», яку носив на поясі через плече.

  (Тут мається на увазі якась зброя, можливо, ніж.)
- «Народне мистецтво», 1997, випуск 1–8, ст. 55:

  > Верстак (Верстат) — <…>. За функцією В. поділяються на: кросна, тканиця, колесня, стелюга, довбальня, столець, токарка-точилка, ослін (для чистки дошок), бетельня, козли тощо.
- Валерій Трипачук, «Четвертий Рим», 1999, ст. 269:

  > Але не за столом за кресленнями і не за токаркою.

А ще іноді вживають і як назву професії для жінки:

- Ірена Книш, «Відгуки часу», 1972, ст. 162:

  > …спайщиці, зчіплювачки, лебідниці, слюсарки, машиністки, токарки, трактороскладачки, машиноконструкторки, механізаторки, будівельниці, бетонярки…